# Use of array to import multiple postal address in AX 2012

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am using the following code to import multiple postal addresses for a customer record in AX 2012 =(Microsoft Dynamics AX) using AIF=(Application Integration Framework).  I am testing this code with a customer record with two postal addresses.  The very first time the code runs (1 st loop), it goes through just fine, but on the second round it fails, giving me array out of bound error.  Any suggestions on what might be causing this error looking at the below code?

```
   index = 0;

    AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView[] array = new  AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView[index];

foreach (DataRow row2 in row.GetChildRows("HdrLine"))
{

    AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView address = 
                                   new AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView

     {
         LocationName = row2["AXDirPartyPostalAddress_LocationName"].ToString(),
         Street = row2["AXDirPartyPostalAddress_Street"].ToString(),
         City = row2["AXDirPartyPostalAddress_City"].ToString(),
         State = row2["AXDirPartyPostalAddress_State"].ToString(),
         CountryRegionId = row2["AXDirPartyPostalAddress_Country"].ToString(),
         ZipCode = row2["AXDirPartyPostalAddress_zipcode"].ToString(),
         Roles = row2["AXDirPartyPostalAddress_AddRoles"].ToString()
     };

    Array.Resize<AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView>(ref array, index + 1);
    array[index] = address;

    custTable.DirParty[index].DirPartyPostalAddressView = 
                    new AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView [] { array[index] };
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more code. By not seeing more about `array` or `index` it is hard to say why you are getting the error.

Comment: Could you please explain what AX and AIF are, so people like me can understand it. Could you also post the exact exception?

Comment: I have added the full code for this loop as well as abreviation details.  Thanks

Comment: @Shazam So far the code looks correct. Could you please add details for `custTable.DirParty`?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, but it appears like you are adding you tmp record into another array, which you haven't increased in size.

Why don't you use lists instead?

```
List<AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView> tmplist = new List<AxdEntity_DirPartyPostalAddressView>();
```